# Timeline divs not showing in Safari 5

Tags: html, css, safari, browser-support

I have an outer `td`, with two `float:left` divs inside. I have a background color for the outer `td`, and a different color for the inner two divs. It is working as intended on all browsers but Safari. In Safari (for Windows 5.1.7) the inner divs and their contents are not showing up at all.

Here is the relevant HTML & CSS:

```css
.timeline {
    width: 400px;   
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 6px solid #191919;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
.timeline p {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
.timeline p:hover {
    color: grey;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.timeline p:hover + b{
    color: red;
}
.tlleft {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
    height: 520px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    background-color: #191919;
}
.tlleft b {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    position:relative;
    font-size: 50px;
    left: 189px;
    top: -55px;    
}
.tlright {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 520px;
    background-color: #191919;
}
.tlright b {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    font-size: 50px;
    right: 11px;
    top: -55px;    
}

#timelinextra {
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #191919;
    background-color: black;  
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right:-300px;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: 200px;
    position:fixed;
    width: 600px;  
    right:50%;
}
#timelinextra a {
    background-color:darkgrey;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-right:2px;
    display:block;       
    margin:10px;
    float:right;
    width:22px;  
}
#timelinextra a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;  
}
#timelinextra p {
    margin: 10px 40px;
    clear:both;  
}
```

```html
    <table style="margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                <!--More content here-->
            </td>
            <td class="timeline">
                <div class="tlleft">
                    <p>Born</p><b>&bull;</b>
                    <br /><br />
                    <p>College</p><b>&bull;</b>
                    <br /><br />
                    <p>Started Work</p><b>&bull;</b>
                    <p>Still Working</p><b>&bull;</b>                    
                </div>                    
                <div class="tlright">
                    <br /><br /><br /><br />
                    <p>Primary School</p><b>&bull;</b>
                    <p>Masters & Diplomas</p><b>&bull;</b>
                    <p>Coding Again</p><b>&bull;</b>
                    <br /><br />
                    <p>Still Coding</p><b>&bull;</b>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czshyush/5/) for those who prefer to check that. The styling is a little off with the above because I have cut out all unnecessary extras. This is the smallest complete workable example I could create that recreates the issue and I am still none the wiser.

Any suggestions for why the inner divs are not showing in Safari 5, or how I could fix it?

Comment: From what I see you don't have outer div, you have a <TD> element. Possible overflow issue since both children are floated?

Comment: @kasperoo - Ah yes, I will amend the question. Although I'm still not sure how that's causing the issue or how I would go about fixing it.

Comment: Do you really need the size of the inner divs to be set in % ? Try using pixels, I had this problem once and using % was what f***ed it up.

Comment: @Alin - The % kind of needs to be there because the timeline needs to be scalable for some later work. That said, I have tried using px specifically and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: What version of Safari are you testing? Is it by any chance Safari for Windows?

Comment: Ok, also, have you tried defining position:relative and adding padding:0?

Comment: @ckuijjer - It is Safari for Windows.

Comment: Safari for Windows hasn't been updated anymore since 2012, it's stuck at version 5 while on OS X it's currently at version 8. If you're doing the testing in Safari to see how it will look on a Mac don't bother with Safari for Windows.

Comment: @ckuijjer - Thanks, that piece of info alone was worth putting the question up for. That does beg the question through, is there really no good way to solve the compatibility issue for Safari 5? The site I am designing otherwise has a very low barrier in terms of compatibility.

Comment: I'm not sure sorry, I don't have access to Safari 5. Perhaps it might have to do with the `display: flex`, I'm not really sure you need that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simplifyyyy Mannn!

### Floats, an ordered list and a sprinkling of pseudo-elements

**Compatibility:**

Safari 3.2+ / IE9+ [using `nth-child`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) and [pseudo elements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) or Safari 3.1+ / IE8+ with classes and [pseudo elements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent).

- A timeline is a great opportunity to use an ordered list (`<ol>`); it is an ordered sequence of events.
- Create the bullets with [`:before` pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) on the list items
- Position with left and right floats using nth-child to select odd and even list items. ([`nth-child` is supported in Safari 5](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3))
- The center line is created with a `:before` pseudo element on the ordered list element

### Full Example

I haven't placed in hover events, but you should have no problem creating those.

```css
.timeline {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 6px solid #191919;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #EEE;
}
.timeline:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 8px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
}
.timeline li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}
li:hover:before {
  background: #F00;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
  clear: left;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="timeline">
  <li>Born</li>
  <li>College</li>
  <li>Started Work</li>
  <li>Still Working</li>
  <li>Primary School</li>
  <li>Masters &amp; Diplomas</li>
  <li>Coding Again</li>
  <li>Still Coding</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Wow, nice. Much more elegant thanks. I see a very minor issue, my current implementation has a different hover effect for the bullets compared to the text itself, which I am not sure is possible with this solution.

Comment: You can target the "bullets" on hover with `li:hover:before { }` and provide whatever effect you wish :) You would change the color with `li:hover:before { background: red }`

Comment: No worries :) I added a hover for the bullets in my example. Note the `transition` which is nice and smooth.